# Hardware mystery I have been trying to solve for the last two years

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, virtualbox, windows-update

My laptop is an Asus zenbook UX430UA and I have this problem I am struggling with for the last 2 years.

It starts when windows updates installs the update from build 1809 to 1903 and above (and win 11), my laptop breaks completely. Windows takes an hour to boot and works super slow which forces me to rollback.

This triggered me and made me want to install Linux, but I have this error which I cant figure out how to solve, I made a seperate thread: [Ubuntu(Or any other linux distro) stuck on retrieving clocksource](https://superuser.com/questions/1612955/ubuntuor-any-other-linux-distro-stuck-on-retrieving-clocksource), all the commandline options given did not solve the problem.

I sent my laptop back to asus repair but they told me that I need to replace the full motherboard. This does not make sense to me since I tested it and windows 7, 8, and 10(until build 1809) all work. The linux distros do work in virtualbox within win 10 1809 but when I try to install natively, I get the problem from the thread. It makes me think that the windows update and the linux kernel not willing to work natively might have a connection(BIOS Problem?).

Is there anyone who experienced this issue and knows a solution or the cause of the problem?

Comment: Updating BIOS firmware I have already tried

Comment: If it’s a UEFI problem then that requires a new motherboard. Without logs that indicates the reason the feature updates are failing we cannot really help other than suggesting you replace the motherboard

Comment: @Ramhound If it would be an UEFI error, then no OS should run no? Receiving logs from the windows installation is quite difficult, logs for linux are in the other thread.

Comment: I can’t solve a Linux problem but I can identify the reasons a feature update is rolled back (with logs), this question, also appears to be about Windows not Linux

Comment: Give it a look to the last comment of [this post](https://superuser.com/q/393969/257269). You should try to isolate your problem (`acpi=off`).